# COCOS2DX open GL issue 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I use COCOS2DX. I tried to change the following syntax cocos2d to cocos2dx.

What is the use of "glTexCoordPointer" in OpenGL1.0?

What is the same syntax in Open GL 2.0?

Can you assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long search, i got this for ES 2.0

The same syntax in OpenGL 2.0 is 
     "glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, coordinates);"
The code syntax:

> ccGLBindTexture2D (tongue->getName());
>
> ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position |
>   kCCVertexAttribFlag_TexCoords);
>
> glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
>   0, vertices);
>
> glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT,
>   GL_FALSE, 0, coordinates)
>
> glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4);
>
> glEnableVertexAttribArray(GL_TEXTURE_2D);